# Handshake error while connecting to Google Vision API using Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-vision, sslerrorhandler

I am using below code to connect to Google Vision API. I have JSON from Google Vision.

The code is giving me below error . Not Sure why.. `< TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE >` 
Please suggest.. It is working fine on Windows Server Machine but not on my Windows 7 machine.

Below is code and Error Details.

```
enter code here

Error details below.
E0410 12:18:28.854000000 17616 src/core/tsi/ssl_transport_security.cc:1239] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED.



grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "Connect Failed"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1554878916.008000000","description":"Failed to create subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":2267,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1554878916.008000000","description":"Pick Cancelled","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/pick_first/pick_first.cc","file_line":242,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1554878916.008000000","description":"Connect Failed","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/subchannel.cc","file_line":962,"grpc_status":14,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1554878916.008000000","description":"Handshake failed","file":"src/core/lib/security/transport/security_handshaker.cc","file_line":291,"tsi_code":10,"tsi_error":"TSI_PROTOCOL_FAILURE"}]}]}]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your windows 7 machine doesn't have up-to-date root certs. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/dn265983(v=ws.11)) suggests that Windows server has auto updates but Windows 7 doesn't.

Another remote possibility is that your windows 7 machine is behind a proxy that uses its own TLS certs and there is a certificate setup issue on your machine.